# Flutter webview - HTML/JS Copy to Clipboard not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I have this following code, in Flutter for Android

https://gist.github.com/edwinyoyada/0b48c69b46409829a666d30818dbf562

Inside, you see that there is Copy to Clipboard functionality written in JS

But if I click it, the content is not copied.

Please help to make it work,

My previous workaround was to use `onPageFinished`

```
onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
            if (url.contains('#bni') || url.contains('#other_banks')) {
              _controller
                  .evaluateJavascript(
                      "window.document.body.getElementsByClassName('mb-4 last:mb-0 font-sans font-light text-2xl text-gray-500');")
                  // .evaluateJavascript(
                  //     "document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('P')[0].innerText;")
                  .then((value) {
                print(value);
                Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: value));
              });
            }
          },
```

But it's not scalable if i have more than one copy button

Thank you